# Extract value from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hello so I am using the callback feature of https://smsgateway.me and my current code is here:

```
<?php
include "smsGateway.php";
$smsGateway = new SmsGateway('email@gmail.com', 'password');

$message = //extract number value from multidimensional array;

$number = "09058789624";
$deviceID = 5495;
$result = $smsGateway->sendMessageToNumber($number, $message, $deviceID);
?>
```

In the documentation of smsgateway.me [here](https://smsgateway.me/sms-api-documentation/callbacks/http-method) I've used every http POST request and as you can see the parameter contact there says that it's a multidimensional array that contains the ID, Name and Number. Now what I wanted to do is to only get the Number. How can I do that?

Comment: The response is in JSON.

Comment: How to do that? If I am getting the message I just use $_POST['message']

Comment: use `var_dump()` function to do that, put the `$_POST['message']` in that `var_dump()` as `var_dump($_POST['message'])`

Comment: yes look at my edited comment

Comment: Call me Sourabh that is fine, no need to call me sir :)

Answer (score 3):

Since the response is in JSON, you would do something like the following:

```
$json = json_decode($result);
echo $json->result->success->contact->number;
```

Of course you should also add error handling, and check to see the object exists, etc.

For reference, I used the documentation outlining the response that is returned when sending a message as specified here: [Send Message to Number](https://smsgateway.me/sms-api-documentation/messages/send-message-to-number)

**The response format (for success)**:

```
{
   "success":true,
   "result":{
      "success":[
         {
            "id":"308",
            "device_id":"4",
            "message":"hello world!",
            "status":"pending",
            "send_at":"1414624856",
            "queued_at":"0",
            "sent_at":"0",
            "delivered_at":"0",
            "expires_at":"1414634856",
            "canceled_at":"0",
            "failed_at":"0",
            "received_at":"0",
            "error":"None",
            "created_at":"1414624856",
            "contact":{
               "id":"14",
               "name":"Phyllis Turner",
               "number":"+447791064713"
            }
         }
      ],
      "fails":[

      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First get the response data and print it, see it's array structure using:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

Based on that, access the data you want.